# TCP Socket programming not working between desktop and android tablet

Tags: java, android, sockets

i've done an application which send datas from server to clients....the code (server & client) works perfectly in desktop application, but when i put client on android tablet and server on desktop., its not working

i'm using wifi for communication between android and desktop

permissions which i've set is as shown below

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

can anyone please tell me what's the problem behind this.....

I'm getting this exception

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.74 (port 4545): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

**Server.java**

```
public class Server
{
  private int TAB_SERVER_PORT = 4545;
  private static PrintWriter TABout;
  private HashSet <PrintWriter> TABhs=new HashSet<PrintWriter>();
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    new Thread(new TABServerThread()).start();
  } 

    private class TABServerThread implements Runnable {
        private ServerSocket TABserver;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                TABserver = new ServerSocket(TAB_SERVER_PORT);
                System.out.println("Server Start the server at port " + TAB_SERVER_PORT + " and waiting for clients...");
                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = TABserver.accept();
                    System.out.println("Server Accept socket connection: "+ socket.getLocalAddress());
                    new Thread(new TABClientHandler(socket)).start();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private class TABClientHandler implements Runnable {
        private Socket clientSocket;
        private Scanner in;
        public TABClientHandler(Socket clietSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clietSocket;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                TABout = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                TABhs.add(TABout);
                in = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                String line;
                while ((line = in.nextLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.equals("Reply")){
                        TABout.print("Server replies");
                        TABout.flush();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
            private int TAB_SERVER_PORT = 4545;
            private Socket tabletclient;
            private PrintWriter tabletout;
            private Scanner in;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                    String line;
                    boolean flag=true;
                    System.out.println("Waiting for server connection....");
                    while(flag){
                    try {
                        tabletclient = new Socket("192.168.1.74", TAB_SERVER_PORT);
                        tabletout = new PrintWriter(tabletclient.getOutputStream());
                        in = new Scanner(tabletclient.getInputStream());
                        try
                        {
                            if((line = in.nextLine())!=null)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Client Server says: " + line);
                                if (line.equals("Hello client")) {
                                    tabletout.println("Reply");
                                    tabletout.flush();
                                }
                            }
                        }catch(Exception d){
                            System.out.println("Connection from server has lost.........");
                        }
                        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        }
                     }
            }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
               new Thread(new Client()).start();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the server allows the connection to this port? Is there a firewall blocking it?

Comment: @Henry sir there's is no firewall..........

Answer (score 0):

It must be the firewall that blocks the connections. You can disable it and try again. Should any more issues, please use wireshark to capture some packets to check where the problem is.

You can try "netstat -n" on both Linux or Windows to see if your server socket is binding and listening there.

Comment: sir how to check whether any firewall is blocking..........can you please tell me how to do that

Comment: What is the OS of your host?

Comment: see my edited answer, did you try the netstat command to check if your server socket is working? If it is there and you can not reach it, then it is the firewall - either 3rd party firewall or default microsoft tools - that is blocking the connection.

Comment: sir i got lots of ips......my android tablet ip is 192.168.1.67 nut it is not there...........

Comment: It is so hard to make a mobile device server.Probably you can easily do it if you make your android device client and desktop server.You know your mobile devices ip can change any time.Your Client.java works on desktop as i see because it has a main method.

Comment: @Ercan it's not hard at all.  You need to stop spreading this bad advice.

Comment: Well, Why don't you give us a working sample so i can learn how bad is my advice.And can you tell me again how your clients know their servers ip everytime?

Comment: sir ..... now i client is connecting to server.....but server can't send any datas...to client using.....out.println("message");

Answer (score -1):

Change your android application into a Client and Desktop application into a server. This way is much easier and safe(in my opinion of course).Your mobile devices ip can change any time due to... you know it is mobile.Your clients cant't guess the ip of their mobile server.

move your Client.java to your android app and Server.java to your desktop app.

Comment: right now it is like that Client.java  in android, and Server.java in Desktop

Comment: try to get your desktops internet ip from http://www.whatismyip.com/
that error means there is no server listening in this port or ip in most cases.

Comment: What does this have to do with the problem at hand?  You can run a server on android as much as you want/

Comment: I said this way is easier.Not impossible. please read whole thing. Your down vote is pointless.

Comment: sir ..... now i client is connecting to server.....but server can't send any datas...to client using.....out.println("message");

Comment: @Ercan you say it's more "safe"  This is not meaningful in any way.  There are plenty of ways of making dynamic IP addresses globally knowable.

Comment: @user2040500 this may happen when you are using readLine and printLn methods. try to send them as byte array then convert to String(String has a constructor for it). And do not forget to trim the string you receive. it may not return true line.equals("Reply") it may have empty spaces.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use "ifconfig" (if you working on Linux)to check your IP address or "ipconfig" if you working on Windows system; make sure your IP address is exactly "192.168.1.74".

Comment: I'v tried many times to found a connection between the android tablet and PC, but it seems worked well only the android tablet set as the server, and PC as the client.